# Getting grub prompt after moving computer to new case

Tags: windows, dual-boot, grub, grub-legacy

I have a computer with several hard drives, one Windows 7 install and one CentOS install.

I moved the computer to a new case and now the BIOS only recognizes one of the disks as bootable, and that disk boots to grub.

I am fairly certain Windows and CentOS are installed on totally separate disks.

I've tried only connecting one hard disk at a time, but the BIOS only recognizes one particular disk as bootable and can only boot that disk into grub. All the other disks are not recognized as bootable.

Has anyone seen this behavior before? Any advice on how to approach the problem?

Comment: have you tried swapping SATA1 and SATA2 on the mainboard, to change detection order?

Comment: Yup. No change in outcome.

Comment: You need to provide more information: There are exactly 2 disks total, or 2 disks with Operating-System and then other disks? In any case, best way forward from here is booting a live-cd, and using it to get partition info from the disks. Edit into your question some of the output of `cat /proc/partitions` and `fdisk -l` and `blkid | sed -E 's/^([^ ]* ).*(TYPE="[^"]*").*$/\1\2/'` and `lsblk`.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how Grub was configured, it may not be finding the drives/partitions in the same place as they were before. For instance if your drives were plugged into the SATA_1, SATA_2, etc ports on the motherboard before, and they are not plugged into the same ports now (particularly if you moved drives to/from a SATA 6gb/s controller), this will change the drive numbering and Grub will be looking for things in the wrong place.

The one suggestion I could offer for fixing this would be to boot with a linux live CD, chroot into the correct linux install and try running `grub2-mkconfig`, which should auto-detect where your various OSes are installed and create a new config file for Grub.

Answer (score 0):

Simply moving your computer to a new case shouldn't affect how it operates. Maybe you reset the CMOS when re-assembling it. If this is the case, check your boot order in the BIOS and make sure the hard drive that GRUB is installed on is present.

Comment: Tried that. The boot order lists the hard drive with grub installed and the CD-ROM drive, nothing else.

Comment: @StudentsTea what happens when you select grub as your boot device? Also, make sure you are in EFI mode if you installed grub in EFI mode.